# How to write using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Can I rewrite the below using Linq.

I am trying to find if the word 'apple' exists in the array.

Ex array: [banana fruit, apple fruit, almond, pineapple]. This returns true as per my below code, as the word apple exist in "apple fruit".

```
 var apple=false    
 foreach (var item in pack.items)
 {   
    if (item.Contains("Apple"))
    {
        apple = true;
    }                                                                                                    
 }
```

I would like to rewrite the same using linq. Thank you.

Comment: `pack.items.Any(item => item.Contains("Apple"))`

Comment: @Enigmativity: That's not the same thing. Suppose `pack.items` contains "Apple Inc". Your code would return false, the original code would return true. (Or indeed the "apple fruit" example in the question.)

Comment: `bool apple = (from i in pack.items where i.Contains("Apple") select i).Any();`,

Comment: From your input: "Apple", the final output apple will be false as the value comparison are case sensitive. To ignore case sensitive, `bool apple = pack.items.Any(x => x.Contains("Apple", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`. For your reference: [`String.Contains(String, StringComparison)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-string-system-stringcomparison))

Comment: or in other words: `"pineapple"` does **not** contain the word `"Apple"`.

Comment: Thank you everyone , sorry for getting back later,  
@canton7 I have tried yours and it works as expected and thank you Yong for including case sensitive comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code below

```
 bool appleExists = array.Any(item => item.Contains("apple", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

The any method will return a boolean value of true if apple contains in the array else will return false. StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase will perform the comparison in case-insensitive manner.